# How to calculate an error-minimizing approximation to a numerical array

Tags: algorithm, optimization, statistics

Given an array of numerical values (integers or floats, either is fine) and a positive integer N, I want to return an array of N values such that, if each value in the original array is replaced by its closest match in the returned array, squared error (i.e. (original_value - approximation) ^ 2) is minimized. Basically, to find a smaller array that best approximates the input array.

The case for N = 1 is trivial, with some basic algebra one can easily show the answer is the mean of the values.

One can also show that after sorting the input array, each "return" value must correspond to a sequential set of values from the input array, its value being their mean. So for N = 2, at worst we can just start with one set with sorted_input[0] and another set with all other values, and one by one sequentially move items to the first set, returning whatever combination minimizes error in O(n) (ignoring the sorting costs)

However, at N = 3 and beyond it's not clear how to proceed. Trying all combinations naively becomes O(n^(N-1)), and although it feels like they should exist, I can't prove any optimizations are "safe" (i.e. won't get stuck in some local minimum that gives a non-optimal result)

It may very well be the case that the problem is actually NP-hard (I can't even figure how to verify a solution in polynomial time!), but it feels like the sort of problem where a bit of mathematical trickery can result in huge speedups, so I figured I would ask for any ideas. Note that I'm looking for the *optimal* solution, not just a decent approximation.

Comment: Did you look at "back and forth error compensation and correction"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept, so I googled and I think I got the gist of it... however, I'm not seeing how to apply it to the problem at hand. What sort of approach were you thinking of?

Comment: if that operation is reversible or achievable opposite direction, you can do 1 forward 1 reverse functions and take error, then from origin go 1 step forward and subtract half of error of 1f1r version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) is a good starting point for your problem. Is short there are many algorithms but they are mostly problem specific.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems what I'm trying to do is essentially [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), which, as I feared, appears to be NP-hard in the general case. However, in the one-dimensional case, I found [a paper that claims to find an optimal solution](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456844.html). While I can't access the full article, a look at the source code suggests it's probably polynomial in time and space. Problem solved?

Comment: Kyme and is widely used,  it has many implementations in many languages and it is a reasonable solution. It does not promise to find the optimal solution, it may converge to a local minima. I will have a look at the paper you suggested, thanks.